# Auto bed leveling with stepper motor lock

Tags: bed-leveling, ramps-1.4, extruder-driver

I have a botObject printer that was discontinued that I want to run using a RAMPS 1.4 board. The bed leveling was done by the print nozzle being pushed down on the spring loaded bed and then the stepper will turn the cam to lock it, this will be repeated at 3 positions on the bed. I want to use one of my extruder outputs to drive the stepper but still need a limit switch to home the cam. I am not a programmer so need assistance with the setup in Marlin  [image: lock can system]

Comment: So the Z axis steppers push down the bed with the nozzle until they skip, at which points the bed leveling screw is locked in place?

That must be the most idiotic ABL approach I've ever seen lol

Comment: Hi Willem, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! @towe you already answered a similar question [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/home-e-extrude-until-endstop-is-triggered)! P.S. I would ditch this system, there are way more simple methods to level a bed, e.g. using an inductive, or touch sensor.